# Авторизация на сайте под доменной учеткой

Tags: c#, авторизация, active-directory

Здравствуйте товарищи.

Ситуация такая: есть доменные учетные записи и есть корпоративный портал, логин/пароль совпадают. Также есть веб-клиент (на основе CefSharp), для которого нужно организовать прозрачную авторизацию - чтобы пользователям не нужно было вводить логин/пароль.

Я пробовал через `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` таким образом:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://example.ru/anythhing/yetanything/");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line = "";
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}

response.Close();
```

Однако сервер возвращает главную страницу, т.е. авторизация не была выполнена. 
Если посмотреть свойство `request.Credentials` в отладчике, то можно заметить, что Domain, UserName и Password - это пустые строки.

У кого-нибудь есть идеи, как это можно сделать?

Comment: в windows окружении прозрачную аутентификацию для сайта относительно несложно сделать на Kerberos. Но это требует дополнительной конфигурации веб-сервера + создание SPN (service principal name). Погуглите для вашего веб-сервера настройки kerberos - различных документаций достаточно.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня нет доступа к серверу (моя задача - клиент). Может есть способ реализовать это без необходимости изменения конфигурации сервера?